# Excel VBA code to read a username from a cell then send an email to that user

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I require some help in creating Excel VBA code which will read a row of usernames from cells in Excel and then send an email to all those users by searching for the users email address in the Outlook contacts list.

I have managed to write the code that will bring up outlook's compose email dialog box from the spreadsheet.

Comment: You need to post what you have so we know where you are stuck.

Comment: You will also need to specify what the username is (first name, last name) or windows logon name (SAMacccountName) etc. With what you have to date you may get away with a simple ResolveRecipients.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **for** in range with mails and call this proc to send email

```
Public Sub SendMail(MailTO As String, MailSubject As String, MailBody As String)
'http://officevb.com

Dim appOL               As Object
Dim myEmail             As Object
Dim TxtHello            As String

Set appOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set myEmail = appOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'Use hour to create a text
Select Case Hour(Time)
    Case Is <= 12
        TxtHello = "Good Morning," & vbNewLine
    Case Is >= 12
        TxtHello = "Good Afternoom," & vbNewLine
    Case Is >= 18
        TxtHello = "Good Night," & vbNewLine
End Select

    With myEmail
      .display
      .Recipients.Add MailTO
      .Subject = MailSubject
      .Body = TxtHello & MailBody
      .Send
    End With

Set myEmail = Nothing
Set appOL = Nothing

End Sub
```

call this sub passing these parameters

sendMail "Mail@yourContact.com","Test","This is a automatic mail"

[]´s

Comment: While you're building your macro, replace `With myEmail ... .Send ` with `With myEmail ... .Display `. This will just bring up the finished email without sending it. Once you have your email/macro finished and ready, uyou can change it back to `.Send`